# Page set NOT to Display, but shows anyway (Mura 6)

Tags: mura

I go into site manager for an old page that we want to disable.  The Display param on the Publish tab is set to "No", but one can still put in the page's url and get to it in the browser.

Is that the way it is supposed to work.

Comment: Are you sure that you published the change after setting Display to No? The page should not be viewable if Display is No.

Comment: I did hit the Publish button.  That should do it, right?

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. Is it still not hidden? To be clear, you did not specify a date range in that box? You did not specify anything in "Content Expiration"?

Comment: No date is set in either "Official Release Date" or "Content Expiration".  Should there be?

Comment: For grins, I put a past date in the Content Expiration field.  Page still shows up.

Comment: No, there should not be a date in any of those others fields. I was just trying to confirm you were not using one of those fields. By setting Display to No the page should only be viewable inside the Mura admin. I'm not sure what is going on with yours.